# Smallest faithful matrix representation of the exterior algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R = \Lambda \mathbb{C}^n$ be the exterior algebra on $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some positive integer $n$. It is an associative (graded-commutative) algebra of $\mathbb{C}$-dimension $2^n$.

Suppose we have an injective ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow M_N(\mathbb{C})$ into the ring $M_N(\mathbb{C})$ of $N\times N$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, for some positive integer $N$. (I.e., a faithful matrix representation of $R$.)

**What's the smallest $N$ can be, and what's the explicit ring map? In particular, can $N$ be smaller than $2^n$?**

I know that $N$ can be taken to be $\leq 2^n$, because we can embed $R$ in $M_{2^n}(\mathbb{C})$ by considering its left action on itself (i.e., its regular representation). Explicitly we get the map $R\rightarrow M_{2^n}(\mathbb{C})$ by choosing a $\mathbb{C}$-basis for $R$ and then sending an element of $R$ to the matrix that represents its left action on that basis.

Meanwhile, I also know $N\geq 2^{n/2}$, because the $\mathbb{C}$-dimension of $M_N(\mathbb{C})$ is $N^2$, so injectivity of $R\rightarrow M_N(\mathbb{C})$ implies immediately that $2^n\leq N^2$.

So $N$ has to be exponential in $n$. But specifically, are there matrix representations smaller than the regular representation? If so, what are they? If not, how can we see this?

(I have verified by hand in the simplest nontrivial case $n=2$ that there's no faithful matrix representation smaller than the regular representation.)

**Aside:** A brief comment on motivation. The question is not motivated by my own research. A colleague asked me it a few months ago. The reason he asked has been rendered moot by subsequent developments in his work, so afaik it's not motivated by his research anymore either. But the question got stuck in my mind because it feels like a very fundamental representation-theoretic question, but I didn't know the answer and I wasn't sure where to look it up, and I asked a few folks who didn't know either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $M$ be a faithful module for $R$, and let $a\in R$ be the product of the exterior generators, so that $a$ generates the socle of $R$. Then there an element $m\in M$ such that $am\ne 0$. The map $r\mapsto rm$ is then an injective homomorphism from the regular representation of $R$ to $M$, so the dimension of $M$ is at least $2^n$.

Comment: And since $R$ is self-injective, this also implies that the regular representation of $R$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of $M$.

Comment: Thanks! The general principle seems to be: a faithful module over an artinian ring with a cyclic socle must contain the regular rep as a submodule. Am I reading this right?

Comment: Here are some references for you:

Gulliksen, "On the length of faithful modules over Artinian local rings," Math Scand 31 (1972) 78-82.

Bergman, "Minimal faithful modules over Artinian rings," Publ Mat 59 (2015), 271-300.

Answer (score 4):

Here a more general result that also applies to non-selfinjective algebras such as the ring of upper triangular matrices: Let $A$ be a finite dimensional basic algebra. Then a module $M$ is faithful if and only if there is an embedding $0 -> A -> M^n$ for some $n \geq 1$. Now if $A$ has the property that the injective hull of $A$ is projective-injective then every faithful module has as a direct summand the direct sum of all indecomposable projective-injective modules. Thus for such $A$ there is a unique smallest faithfulmodule given by the basic version of the injective hull of $A$.
When $A$ is selfinjective (which the exterior algebra is), then the smallest faithful module is just $A$.

Comment: I don't think your last statement is true for two by two matrices over a field. You may be thinking of the case where $A$ is basic.

Comment: @DaveBenson Thanks, I added that condition.